# Camera screen goes to dark when return from another activity -- Android

Tags: android, android-camera

In my program I used the camera to take a video and preview. Both happens in a SurfaceTexture. After preview when i go back to previous page for take another video, the Texture went to full dark and nothing happen.

It shows

- Failed to open camera service
- dequeueBuffer: can't dequeue multiple buffers without setting the buffer count

So anyone help me to solve this issue

Comment: release the acquire of camera during onPause/onDestroy in order to release the camera function when you are not using it, and recall the acquire camera function during onCreate/onResume

Comment: post your code and error from the log. so that it will be easier to give proper answer.